# Features Posts / Featured list WP Slider plugins?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

For some reason I can't find any working / recent Wordpress plugins that have the featured content / list that are on the right of slider window.

**EG:** [image]

Does anyone know where I can find any to use?

Comment: I wrote up a quick tutorial for something like this [click here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46673/how-do-i-create-a-custom-wordpress-slideshow-plugin/46685#46685). I hope this helps! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeCanyon is a great resource if you havent already visited it check it out. You will have to pay for most plugins but most are of a high standard.

Here are a few i found for you:

This one is very configurable and allows multiple layouts:
http://codecanyon.net/item/premium-featured-posts-slider/full_screen_preview/163255

This one is free and would be a piece of cake to make look like you example:
http://www.featuredcontentgallery.com/

Remember using some really simple CSS you can make alterations to sliders to suit your requirements.

Hope that helps